# No visibility of the variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have class:

**IMIS.MASTER.vb**

```
Public Class IMIS
    Protected Friend imisgen As New IMIS_Gen
```

**IMIS.MASTER**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var searchCHF = '<%#imisgen.getMessage("L_SEARCHCHFNUMBER", True)%>';
</script>
```

[image]

I have error in `var searchCHF = '<%#imisgen.getMessage("L_SEARCHCHFNUMBER", True)%>';`:

Error:

`BC30451 'imisgen' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. 2_IMIS.Master`

What is wrong?

Comment: Try making Public your getMessage into IMIS_Gen.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj The method is as public. I think there is a problem with some configuration or version of something

Comment: This happen even you make public your imisgen variable?

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Yes

Comment: Is class IMIS in the same VS Project as the ASP.NET app (i.e. the same assembly)? If not, it's the Protected Friend declaration that won't let the web app access the imisgen variable (which probably should be declared as `Protected Friend Property`).